# CORS error with socket-io connections on Chrome v88+ and Nestjs server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I have an application connecting to a Nestjs server to establish a WS connection (server is on a different URL, so it is a CORS request).

The WebsocketGateway is defined as such.

```
@WebSocketGateway(port, {
  handlePreflightRequest: (req, res) => {
    const headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'the page origin',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end();
  }
})
```

Works like a charm on Chrome v87 and down and on Firefox.  Since upgrading my browser to Chrome 88, the front-end socket-io connection goes on a connect-reconnect loop, as:

1. The preflight request passes and gets a 200 response, with the headers set above;
2. The actual connection fails with `CORS error` as the only message in the browser console

Answer (score 68):

Just incase someone else needs this, in your decorator there is a cors property

```
@WebSocketGateway({ cors: true })
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me. Should be accepted as the right answer.

Comment: This did the trick!
Just one small note to remember to align the versions of socket.io between server and client (I was stuck in this issue, even after adding cors: true when using different versions).

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I was diving down a nasty rabbit hole of code trying to get this to work. This really needs to be in the core documentation!

Comment: If I set it to only true, does it restrict connections?
How do I restrict the connections?

Comment: It worked as expected, but I am still getting the message in the console: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed:`

Comment: Thanks! That works for me! (it very helps for deploying on Heroku)

Answer (score 17):

This is how i fixed

```
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
import { ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';

export class SocketAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  createIOServer(
    port: number,
    options?: ServerOptions & {
      namespace?: string;
      server?: any;
    },
  ) {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, { ...options, cors: true });
    return server;
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new SocketAdapter(app));
```

Comment: It works thank you. But I don't know if it's normal to do that . I think it must be implemented directly in Nest or should be in the documentation

Comment: That was really great! It finished many hours of total desolation. : )

Comment: You saved my life after hours of fixing the issue. Legend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cookie authentication ensure you set the credential cors property to true. For example:

```
@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: [IPs],
    credentials: true,
  },
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem connecting to a WebSocket which always gives me CORS Error in network tab. fixed that issue by adding `transports` object to socket instance as follows.

```js
   const socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
      transports: ['websocket'],
    });
```

ref: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/641